# How do I keep my laptop running applications / connected to the internet while closed?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook

I'm looking for a way to retain my Internet connection / application running while I'm physically moving in a office WiFi network or VPN **AND** have a closed laptop.

Assuming the routers can reach far enough, what should I do to keep my Mac connected to the internet and running applications while it is closed?

Comment: With MACs that is a pretty bad idea, the majority of air flow is from between the keyboard/screen attachment and it draws from the keyboard.  Blocking the keyboard will mean that you inhibit airflow and increase the temperature of the computer...  That being said, you could use software like [NoSleep](http://modmyi.com/content/6922-nosleep-lets-your-macbook-run-even-when-closed.html), but I wouldn't encourage it if you don't have another way to boost heat dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well move that to an answer:

**Warning**:  Most laptops, but macs especially, draw air through the keyboard and spit it out the vents (in macs that is between the screen hinge and the lower base).  So closing the lid and leaving it running is going to decrease airflow, read: increase heat.  While I discourage you leaving your laptop closed and running software, this can be done.

Easiest method, is use a 3rd party program (since Apple doesn't have this easily built in, AFAIK).

> [NoSleep](http://modmyi.com/content/6922-nosleep-lets-your-macbook-run-even-when-closed.html)
>   NoSleep is a tool that permits you to keep your MacBook, MacBook Pro, or MacBook Air operating even after you have closed the lid. This can be particularly useful if you are the kind of person that needs to let your computer work while you are asleep or when you want to take your computer with you somewhere. It’s great for taking the computer places so that you can close the lid even though you want it to continue processing whatever it was processing when you had it opened up. It's also great for servers if you just happen to use your MacBook for one. If you use your MacBook as a base computer but like to attach it to an external display, then you will appreciate this application.

Again, if you decide to do this, be mindful of your temperatures and try to find an additional cooling method.  **Do not** put your laptop in anything enclosed as you walk around/move positions, unless you like a block of aluminum with an usuable screen.